# ASP.NET Core Scaffolding Error VS 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-2.0, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Using asp.net Visual Studio 2017 I tried to learn making website using MVC. For that I took the reference of this link:
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro
then when to use scaffolding... Some error occured. It occurred even before. I tried to for a solve but still don't get it. Please help me learning MVC.

1. The state before pressing Add . UniversityContext.cs code is here -

[image: View before pressing ADD button]

2. The Error that shows after pressing Add Button.

[image: Error Dialog Box]

Comment: Add a try catch block and give the detailed error . It will help to understand the real problem

Comment: Make sure CodeTemplates folder correctly pickups the files you have specified , multiple versions of VS can create problem

Answer (score 0):

Scaffolding will not run unless the project builds without errors.

Fix the problem shown in the error message.